# Need open a link from a iframe in the self window

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a page where I open some iframes with fancy box, in the content of the iframe, i have some links, when I click these links the page open in the iframe.

I need that the pages open from links on iframe load in the same tab or new window that opens the iframe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simply use this code in your iframe for links:

```
<a target="_blank" href="url">
```

Comment: what about `target="_top"` or `target="_parent"` instead?

Comment: do you want to open that in same iframe? or in new window ?
   i thought you want to open in new window

Comment: I try, _blank target opens in new tab, i need open it in the same tab